# Is it possible to use OpenMP library with Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, openmp

Is it possible to use OpenMP library with Android NDK?

Maybe somebody already tried to compile them together and can provide some hints?

With appearance of dual-core tablets/smartphones I think it would be really nice to use OpenMP capabilities in apps development.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know anything about Android, but looking at the documentation the NDK does say that the pthread library is supported.  Since the gcc implementation of OpenMP is based on pthreads, it would seem to be possible as long as the compiler used supports OpenMP.  Right now the NDK doesn't seem to support it and until it does it would most likely be best to stay with pthreads.

Comment: We can however do something very similar to OpenMP, right in Java+JNI, e.g.: [Parallel.java](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/trunk/javacv/src/com/googlecode/javacv/Parallel.java). I have not tested the performance on Android, but for my applications the Java concurrency classes of OpenJDK + native JNI functions is actually faster than GCC's OpenMP!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For people coming across this question now: OpenMP is supported in the NDK with GCC as of October 2013 (NDK version 9b). See: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html

where they explain to add:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fopenmp
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fopenmp
```

to your Android.mk in order to enable OpenMP support.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/a547eac5446035b4?pli=1), OpenMP ist not supported yet.

A community patch for this is entirely possible, and as mentioned in the discussion it mainly requires modifications to gcc/libgomp.

Comment: See my answer; this is no longer accurate as OpenMP support has been added.