# Android with OpenMP

Tags: android, android-ndk, openmp

I'm creating new project in **Android Studio 2.2.2 with NDK Support.** I'm trying to add OpenMP library via

```
#include <omp.h>
```

but it doesn't work. Also I tried to add:

```
cFlags " -fopenmp" /or/ cppFlags " -fopenmp"
```

but it returns **Build command failed** error. Beforehand there was *Android.mk* file, but now I've got only **CMakeLists.txt** without any flags.

Could somebody help me with issue?

Comment: In the absence of  gcc -v quotation showing enable-libgomp this to be expected.

Comment: @tim18 can you please elaborate ? if enable-libgomp is missing how do I add it to gcc ? thanks

Comment: I don't know to what extent gcc for Android supports OpenMP, but you would need to configure and rebuild your Android targeted GCC

Comment: with added configure options --enable-libgomp --enable-threads=posix

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375028/is-it-possible-to-use-openmp-library-with-android-ndk

Answer (score 6):

After small research, I found out [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html).

I had to change my Android Toolchain from default (clang) to gcc, so my **build.gradle** file looks like that:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.package.com"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc"
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -fopenmp"
            }
        }
    }
```

The most important thing is cmake with **arguments** and **cppFlags**. Those small things should do the job.

Comment: CMake Error ...
GCC is no longer supported.